# OpenGL: Out of texture memory?

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks, textures

I'm writing a little game using OpenGL (in Java through JOGL, but I hardly think that matters), and I have lately been getting quite some error reports of people getting OpenGL errors "1285", which seem to indicate "out of memory". I catch this when checking `glGetError` after having created new textures, which lends me the feeling that I'm running out of texture memory.

However, this surprises me a bit. Isn't OpenGL supposed to manage texture memory for me, swapping textures between the GPU and process memory as necessary? The specifications for `glTexImage2D`, for sure, does not include any "out of memory" error as any of the possible error conditions.

Is this generally accepted practice for OpenGL drivers in spite of the specifications? Are only some drivers doing this in spite of the specifications? Do I need to take care to delete textures that haven't been used for a while if I catch this error after `glTexImage2D`? Or am I perhaps seeing something completely else here that OpenGL's error reporting doesn't quite concisely convey to me?

Edit: For further information, I cannot, unfortunately, debug the problem myself, because I'm not getting it. Reading from the reports people send me, the vast majority of those afflicted by this appear to be using Intel cards, but I've spotted a few nVidia cards as well (even a 680).

Answer (score 1):

It's only a guess, but your program may suffer from address space fragmentation. And if that is the case it indeed matters, that you're running in a Java runtime.

OpenGL, namely the implementation, must keep copies of all data objects, so that it can swap them out on demand. But those copies, they need address space of your process. And if your process environment does a lot of allocations/deallocations, which is the very nature of Java (creating an object for just about everything) it can happen that your address space gets fragmented to the point, that larger chucks can not longer be allocated.

A few points to check: Is your program running on a 32 bit or a 64 bit JRE. If it's a 32 bit executable, try out what happens if you use a 64 bit JRE. If the issues vanish in a 64 bit environment, while on the same machine in a 32 bit environment they are there, it's a address space fragmentation issue for sure.

Comment: I wish I could try out things myself, but unfortunately it is not I getting any errors, so I can only look at the body of reports I'm getting. Unfortunately, almost none of those are from 64-bit JREs at all, so I can't do much of a comparison.

Comment: I do doubt it's a case of address space fragmentation, however. The JRE allocates its heap in a contiguous mapping (512 MB in this case), so the frequent allocations inside it shouldn't affect memory allocation of OpenGL, and I haven't ever seen the JRE process get so large as to warrant concerns of simply running out of address space. The whole process only takes around 1 GB of resident memory, so barring severe fragmentation, there should be lots of virtual space left, I think.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Of the address space remaining, is there enough *contiguous* space to hold large texture images?

Comment: I don't quite see how there couldn't be. The entire virtual size of the JVM process is not hardly more than a gigabyte, so there should be at least two gigabytes of address space left. Within those two gigabytes, I find it hard to believe that there wouldn't be a few megabytes of contiguous space. I don't see how weirdly it would have otherwise been allocated. :)